# No Datasources for `DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM` even when watch connected

Tags: android, wear-os, google-fit, google-fit-sdk, google-fit-api

I have a wearable device where Google Fit is connected with the same account as of my phone. The wearOS device is also connected to my phone.

However the following code returns no data sources corresponding to the `DataType.TYPE_HEIGHT, DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM, DataType.TYPE_HEART_POINTS, DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA` data points.

```
    private val fitnessOptions = FitnessOptions.builder()
        .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
        .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_HEART_POINTS, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
        .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
        .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_HEIGHT, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
        .build()
    
fun setUp() {
        val signInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestProfile()
            .requestScopes(Fitness.SCOPE_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE, Fitness.SCOPE_BODY_READ_WRITE)
            .addExtension(fitnessOptions)
            .build()
        GoogleSignIn.getClient(activity, signInOptions).apply {
            activity.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 1234)
        }
        account = GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(activity, fitnessOptions)

    }

private fun findDataSources() {
        Fitness.getSensorsClient(activity, account)
            .findDataSources(
                DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
                    .setDataTypes(
                        DataType.TYPE_HEIGHT,
                        DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM,
                        DataType.TYPE_HEART_POINTS,
                        DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA,
                        DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE
                    )
                    .setDataSourceTypes(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
                    .build()
            )
            .addOnSuccessListener { dataSources ->
                Timber.i("Play fitness $dataSources")
                dataSources.forEach {
                    Timber.i("Data source found: ${it.streamIdentifier}")
                    Timber.i("Data Source type: ${it.dataType.name}")
                    addSensorListener(it)
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Timber.e(e)
            }
    }

    private fun addSensorListener(dataSource: DataSource) {
        val listener = OnDataPointListener { dataPoint ->
            for (field in dataPoint.dataType.fields) {
                val value = dataPoint.getValue(field)
                Timber.i("Detected DataPoint field: ${field.name}")
                Timber.i("Detected DataPoint value: $value")
            }
        }

        Fitness.getSensorsClient(activity, account)
            .add(
                SensorRequest.Builder()
                    .setDataSource(dataSource) // Optional but recommended for custom data sets.
                    .setDataType(dataSource.dataType) // Can't be omitted.
                    .setSamplingRate(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build(),
                listener
            )
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                when (task.isSuccessful) {
                    true -> Timber.i("Listener registered!")
                    else -> Timber.e(task.exception)
                }
            }
    }
```

I do get data source for `DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE` which is my phone.

My wearOS device is **Fossil Gen 5 Carlyle**

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is your app running on the Wear OS device itself or on the phone? Only the phone's sensors count when you're running on the phone (and vice versa when running on the Wear OS device). Otherwise, they're completely independent.

Comment: Running on the phone. So we can't get sensor data while running on Phone? Can we record a session without running code on WearOS device?

Thank you so much for your reply Ian :)

Comment: A Wear OS device is a completely independent Android device from a sensor perspective. If you attached a separate Bluetooth heart rate monitor to your phone, that should certainly show up as a data source on the phone.

Comment: Got it! It looks like then we need to make an app for wearOS device.

Sorry if this is a stupid question: a wearOS device communicates with the phone via bluetooth only I assume? So is this a design choice to prevent reading sensor data?

Answer (score 1):

If you install the "Fitness API for Android" application on your *Phone Device*, you will not be able to get the raw sensors of the *Watch Device*, only the sensors on the *Phone Device*.

The description in the official documentation confuses us a lot. I have consumed a large amount of time to investigate this.

This means that "Raw Sensor" in "Fitness API for Android" is the same as "SensorManager" in Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

"Wearable device" and "phone" provide little information what you're actually talking about.
Likely you'll have to add support for the HR sensor on WearOS, as it is described in [Support Additional Sensors](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/new-sensors)... where the sensor is even the one you cannot read out:

```
<service android:name="com.example.MySensorService"
         android:process=":sensor">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.fitness.service.FitnessSensorService" />
    <!-- include at least one mimeType filter for the supported data types -->
    <data android:mimeType="vnd.google.fitness.data_type/com.google.heart_rate.bpm" />
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Obvuously, you'd also need to implement your own sensor-specific [`FitnessSensorService`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/service/FitnessSensorService).